# Showing the Gaussian width of a parallelepiped is proportional to sum of its length, width and height?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, probability-theory, optimization, expected-value

Consider a parallelepiped in dimension $3$, $P$, with length $l$, height $h$ and width $w$.  Is it possible to show that its Gaussian width satisfies the following:

$\mathbb E[\sup\limits_{x \in P}\langle x,X\rangle]\sim \text{const}\times( l+h+w)$ where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, Id_{3})$

Any ideas?